# How to use static imports in Glitch?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, import

For the life of me, I can't understand how to use ES6 static imports in a simple Glitch.com project. I found this [project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flavio-es-modules-example?path=index.html:2:0) where someone uses a static import with *no extra* node modules or anything installed.

I basically want to run the *same* example on a new Glitch project now.

I've tried installing all sorts of node modules and packages to support these imports. Here's my current list of dependencies from my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
    "@types/express": "^4.17",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs": "*",
    "babel-node": "^6.5.3",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0"
  },
```

I've spent hours trying to find a solution, but most seem to use outdated packages. Is there something that's different in the environment of the project I linked and that of a new Glitch project now?

Comment: Hey @suds-p! Here's an almost-file-for-file copy of Flavio's proof of concept in an Express-style app on Glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/heathered-pint, but I imagine your end goal is a more complex result - as you noted you don't need any NPM packages to achieve this. (disclaimer, I work at Glitch)

Comment: @cori thank you! that's very helpful. I'm not sure how he achieved that result without NPM packages but I don't mind since I'm using NPM in my project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Glitch project you linked from Flavio is a static site with no backend, package.json or server. It's a great example of ES6 modules but if you're working with Express (I assume so based on its presence in your package.json), converting the example may be non-obvious.

I notice you also have TS in your package.json, but I don't want to be too presumptuous so I'll stick to vanilla in the interests of communicating the simplest possible setup. [Try it on Glitch](https://es6-modules-express.glitch.me/).

Directory structure:

```
public
  math
    add.js
  index.html
  index.js
  style.css
server.js
package.json
```

`public/math/add.js`:

```
export default (a, b) => a + b;
```

`public/index.js`:

```
import add from "./math/add.js";

document.body.textContent = `1 + 2 = ${add(1, 2)}`;
```

`public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Glitch!</title>
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/edit/favicon-app.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "es6-modules-express",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "es6 modules served statically with express",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}
```